# Display the data as a form after being input in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Form:

[image: This is my form.]

Input data:

[image: This is my input data.]

I have a problem displaying the data as a form after being input in Google Sheets. I using form[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzTnx.png) to input data to another sheet [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRCln.png) then now I want show inputted data in form [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzTnx.png). This is my input file code

```
function submitData() {
var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var formSS    = ss.getSheetByName("フォーム"); //Form Sheet
var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName("データ管理"); //Data Sheet

//Input Values
var values = [
  [formSS.getRange("D3").getValue(),//title
  formSS.getRange("D7").getValue(),//number
  formSS.getRange("D9").getValue(),//daytime
  formSS.getRange("I9").getValue(),//Check data
  formSS.getRange("D13").getValue(),//input1
  formSS.getRange("D21").getValue(),//input2
  formSS.getRange("D30").getValue(),//input3
  formSS.getRange("D39").getValue(),//input4
  formSS.getRange("C50").getValue(),//Implementation date
  formSS.getRange("C55").getValue(),//Date of enactment
  formSS.getRange("J50").getValue(),//管理者
  formSS.getRange("J55").getValue()//制定者]
];

datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 12).setValues(values);
}
```

This is my link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FyM3xaDE6LhdHSxwIBrw-NAx1Mcn_Dezzgi_JWJtDWU/edit?usp=sharing
Please help me!

Comment: Unfortunately, from your question, I cannot understand about `I want to display the data as a form after being inputted in Google sheet`. And also, I cannot understand about the relationship between your script and your goal. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: お返事ありがとうございます。
僕やりたいことは入力されたデータをフォームとして表示したいです。

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor understanding. Unfortunately, I cannot image about `入力されたデータをフォームとして表示`. Can you provide the sample input and output you expect? And also, I cannot understand about the relationship between your script and your goal. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: I explain in the photo I post below the comment section

Comment: Thank you for adding more information. In your goal, you want to retrieve the values from Spreadsheet and put the Google form. And you want to see the Google form inputted the values. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, can you provide the sample Google form? By the way, I think that you posted the additional information as the answer. So please delete it and add it to your question.

Comment: Are you using the Google Form Application, or is the form in your sheet?  The link you attached has a form in Sheet 1 and Sheet 2

Comment: What is your script doing that is different to what you would like?

Comment: Thank you for reply. I have solved that problem .